# PageMap contents are not working in Google search results

Tags: google-custom-search, google-rich-snippets

I have added PageMap in two of my html pages also I added PageMap in sitemap for another two html pages
The sitemap is indexed by Google but the contents are not shown in Google search results
Does pagemap only work in custom search engines?

It would be greatful if someone help me out on this. I want to make some sitelinks appear in Google search results for my page

Answer (score 0):

Pagemap is specific to Programmable Search Engine (formerly known as Custom Search Engine), and is not used in search on google.com

For google.com, look at https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your reply. Will try the one you suggested above

Comment: Hi, I have added breadcrumb for my html file and google has indexed it. But I couldn't click the items listed in the breadcrumb. Is there any fix to do to make them clickable?